# Why is が added at the end of この小娘が?

Tags: particles, sentence-final-particles

Why is が added at the end of この小娘が? Is something being omitted here? Is it just a figure of speech?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nothing is omitted there.

This 「が」 is a sentence-ending particle expressing insult, swearing, cussing, etc.
It is often pronounced 「がっ」 by us native speakers, too.

> 「この小娘{こむすめ}が（っ）！」

Thus means:

> "You little slip of a girl!" or
>
> "You little bi***!"

The "right" translation will always depend on the context.

Lastly, the suffix of insult 「め」 is often inserted between the noun and the 「が（っ）」 (but not in that clip).

To be fair, it can be hard to say 「こむす**めめ**」 with the double-め when the last thing you want to do in cussing is to stutter.

Comment: So it's a sentence ending particle the same as わ、ぞ、ぜ?

Comment: @ZeeK It's obviously different in terms of syntax.